# Combine all key values into one NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a JSON file:

```
{
      "locations": [

    { "ingredients" : "Biscuits\n3 cups All-purpose Flour\n2 Tablespoons Baking Powder\n1/2 teaspoon Salt\nShortened for example” },

    { "ingredients" : "12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)\n1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)\nShortened for example” },  
    //many more records.  only included 2 for example                            
      ]
    }
```

I'm getting the "ingredients" key into an array with the code below, but NSLog returns each "ingredients" key separate.

*NSLog example:*

(Biscuits

Flour),

(Rolls

Beef)

This would be fine except that it prevents me from sorting All ingredient values alphabetically and prevents me from removing ALL duplicate values across ALL "ingredients" dictionaries.  I don't control the JSON file so can't combine them manually.  **Can anyone recommend the proper code to get all "ingredients" key values combined into one?**

*Desired Results example:*

(Biscuits

Flour

Rolls

Beef)

```
@implementation JSONLoaderIngreds

- (NSArray *)ingredientsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response  error:nil];

    // NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


    // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
    NSMutableArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"];

 for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {

        NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
        NSMutableString *removewords = [string mutableCopy];
        CFStringTrimWhitespace((__bridge CFMutableStringRef) remove words);


//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\EDIT Added Code Below//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\

[removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"[0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"tablespoons " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cups " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];
        [removewords replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"cup " withString:@"" options:1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [removewords length])];

//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\EDIT Added Code Above//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\


 NSArray *brokenIntoParts = [removewords componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [brokenIntoParts sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
        for (NSString *ingredient in sortedArray) {
            [locations addObject:ingredient];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
    }
return locations;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey As per my understanding here i have simplified your data **ingredients** what you want after all serialisation as mention below:

```
@implementation JSONLoaderIngreds

- (NSArray *)ingredientsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response  error:nil];

    // NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


    // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Replaced Code with sort irritation

    for(NSString *ingredientsStr in [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"] valueForKey:@"ingredients"]){
        [locations addObjectsFromArray:[ingredientsStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];
    }


    return locations;
}
```

After run above this code you will get below output with all **ingredients** data in single array.

```
(
    Biscuits,
    "3 cups All-purpose Flour",
    "2 Tablespoons Baking Powder",
    "1/2 teaspoon Salt",
    "Shortened for example",
    "12 whole Dinner Rolls Or Small Sandwich Buns (I Used Whole Wheat)",
    "1 pound Thinly Shaved Roast Beef Or Ham (or Both!)",
    "Shortened for example"
)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: if above answer resolved your issue please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Will try tonight and let you know how it works.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, but to no fault of yours as I realized not all of the code pasted correctly in the original question.  I edited the question and added the missing code which does replaceOccurrencesOfString.  How code I implement your code without losing this functionality?  Could you update your answer with how you would suggest doing this?  Thanks again.